# Expand width to the left and the right from center with css transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I want my navbar, which **has a fix width** and is centered, on page scrolling to expand left and right from its center. Currently it's just jumping to its new width.

I set up a demo which you can see what I'm trying to do:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qyozvd

(Better look at the demo on codepen.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);

  $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("navbar-toggle-fix");
 });

});

var header, logo, yPos, windowWidth, headerCollapse, mbsp;
function yScroll() {
    header = document.getElementById('header');
    logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    headerCollapse = document.getElementById('headerCollapse');
    mbsp = document.getElementById('mbsp');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    windowWidth = $(document).width();

    if (yPos > 10) {

        header.style.height = "69px";
        $(headerCollapse).removeClass('container');
        $('#logo').addClass('LogoCollapse');
        $('.navbar').addClass('mb-navbarCollapse');

        if (windowWidth > 768) {

         //mbsp.style.height = "0px";

        }

        if (windowWidth < 768) {
        }

    } else {

        header.style.height = "186px";
        $(headerCollapse).addClass('container');
        $('#logo').removeClass('LogoCollapse');
  $('.navbar').removeClass('mb-navbarCollapse');

  

        if (windowWidth > 768) {

         //mbsp.style.height = "186px";
            logo.style.width = "137px"
            logo.style.height = "69px"
            logo.style.backgroundSize = "137px auto"

        }

        if (windowWidth > 1024) {

            logo.style.width = "160px"
            logo.style.height = "119px"
            logo.style.backgroundSize = "160px auto"

        }

        if (windowWidth < 768) {
        }
        
    }

}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);

//Function to the css rule
function checkSize(){
    if ($(".mqJquery").css("float") == "none" ){
        
  $(function() {
    var $el, leftPos, newWidth;
    var $mainNav = $(".nav-tabs");
    var activeItem = $(".nav-tabs .active")[0] ? $($(".nav-tabs .active")[0]) : null;
    var itemLinks = $(".nav-tabs li a");

    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    if (activeItem) {
      $magicLine
        .width(activeItem.width())
        .css("left", activeItem.position().left)
        .data("orig-left", activeItem.position().left)
        .data("orig-width", $magicLine.width());
    } else {
      $magicLine.width(0);
    }

    itemLinks.hover(function() {
      $el = $(this);
      leftPos = $el.parent().position().left;
      newWidth = $el.parent().width();

      if (activeItem == null && $magicLine.position().left === 0) {
        $magicLine.css("left", leftPos + newWidth / 2);
      }

      $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
      });
    }, function() {
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("orig-left"),
        width: $magicLine.data("orig-width")
      });
    });
  });
        
    }
}

// ADD SLIDEDOWN ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(500, "easeOutBounce");
});

// ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(500, "easeOutBounce");
});
```

```css
/* Basic styles */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic);

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-color:#cfcfcf;
 font-family: 'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

.mqJquery {
 float:left;
}

.clearfix {
 clear: both;
}

/* Headings */

h1 {}
h2 {}
h3 {}
h4 {}
h5 {}
h6 {}

/* Color Theme */

.mb-bg-red {
 background-color:#fd100a;
}

.mb-font-red {
 color:#fd100a;
}

.mb-bg-darkgrey {
 background-color: #3e3e3e;
}

.mb-red-grid-pattern {
 background-image: url('img/red-grid-pattern.png');
 background-repeat:repeat;
}

.mb-darkgrey-grid-pattern {
 background-image: url('img/darkgrey-grid-pattern.png');
 background-repeat:repeat;
}

/* Header styles */

header {
 background-image: url('img/header-pattern.png');
 border-top:4px solid #fd100a;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 transition: height 0.2s linear 0s, top 0.2s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.2s linear 0s, top 0.2s linear 0s;
 -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
 background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}

/* Navbar responsive styles */

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight:500;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 150ms linear;
 -moz-transition: background-color 150ms linear;
 -o-transition: background-color 150ms linear;
 -ms-transition: background-color 150ms linear;
 transition: background-color 150ms linear;
}

.navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #a41d1d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
    border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    float:none;
}

.navbar-default,
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form,
.nav-tabs {
    border-color: transparent;
}

.nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #a41d1d;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #a41d1d;
}

.navbar .open .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.navbar .open  .dropdown-menu > li > a {
 color:#fff;
}

.navbar .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
 color:#a41d1d;
}

.navbar .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
 background-color:#a41d1d;
}

.nav > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.nav > li > a {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

 /* Animated navbar collapse icon */

 .navbar-toggle-fix {
  padding-left: 12px;
     padding-right: 8px;
 }

 .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
     width: 22px;
     transition: all 0.2s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
     position:relative;
     padding-top:10px;
     z-index:100
 }
 .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform-origin: 10% 10%;
     -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 10%;
 }
 .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
     opacity: 0;
 }
 .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
     transform-origin: 10% 90%;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 90%;
 }
 .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
     transform: rotate(0);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
 }
 .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
     opacity: 1;
 }
 .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
     transform: rotate(0);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
 }

/* Content styles */

#content {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

/* Footer styles */

footer {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 448px;
   background-color: #515151;
}

/* Layout styles */

#logo {
    background-image:url('img/logo.png');
 height: 67px;
 width: 90px;
    background-size: 67px auto;
    transition:all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s;
    margin-top:7px;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

 .mqJquery {
  float:none;
 }

}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {



}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 

 /* Navbar styles */

 .navbar {
  height:64px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right:-30px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 150px;
     -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }

 .container {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
     transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }

 .mb-navbarCollapse {
  width: 100%;
  top:0px;
  background-color: #515151;
  background-image: url('img/darkgrey-grid-pattern.png');
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 1s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 1s ease-in-out;
     transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out, top 0.5s ease-in-out, background-color 0.5s ease-in-out, background-image 1s ease-in-out;
 }

 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav .open > a, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav .open > a:focus, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav .open > a:hover, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav-tabs > li > a:hover, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav > li > a:focus, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav > li > a:hover, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav-tabs > li.active > a, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, 
 .mb-navbarCollapse .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
     color: #f9131b !important;
 }

 .nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }

 #magic-line {
     background: #3e3e3e none repeat scroll 0 0;
     top: 0px;
     height: 0.2em;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100px;
 }

 .nav-tabs {
     border-bottom: 0 none;
 }

 .nav-tabs:hover {
     border-bottom: 1 none;
 }
 .nav .open > a, .nav .open > a:focus, .nav .open > a:hover,
 .nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
 .nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover,
 .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
  border: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: #3e3e3e;
     cursor:pointer;
     padding: 23px 16px;
     -webkit-transition: color 150ms linear;
     -moz-transition: color 150ms linear;
     -o-transition: color 150ms linear;
     -ms-transition: color 150ms linear;
     transition: color 150ms linear;
 }

 .nav > li > a {
     padding: 22px 15px;
 }

 .nav-tabs > li {
     float:left;
 }

 .navbar .open .dropdown-menu {
     background-clip: padding-box;
     background-color: #fff;
     border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
     border-radius: 4px;
     box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
     display: none;
     float: left;
     font-size: 14px;
     left: 0;
     list-style: outside none none;
     margin: 0;
     min-width: 160px;
     padding: 5px 0;
     position: absolute;
     text-align: left;
     top: 100%;
     z-index: 1000;
 }

 .navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
     color: #3E3E3E;
 }

 .navbar .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
     color: #fff;
 }
 
 /* Header style*/

 header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
     height: 186px;
     
 }

 #headerCollapse {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }

 /* Content styles */

 #content {
  margin-top:20px;
 }

 /* Layout styles */

 #logo {
  height: 119px;
  width: 160px;
     background-size: 160px auto;
  margin-top:17px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
 }

 .LogoCollapse {
  background-size: 64px auto !important;
     height: 48px !important;
     left: 25% !important;
     margin-top: 7px !important;
     position: absolute !important;
     width: 64px !important;
     z-index: 9999 !important;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

    <title>Muth Bau</title>
  
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://mirsoftware.de/muthbau/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  </head>
<body>
    <div class="mqJquery"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <header id="header">
      <div id="headerCollapse" class="container">
        <a href="#"><div id="logo"></div></a>
        <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top mb-bg-red mb-red-grid-pattern">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div aria-expanded="false" id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ÜBER UNS</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SERVICE <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IMPRESSUM</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="mbsp" style="height:186px;"></div>
    <section id="content" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>blabla beispiel text</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>blabla beispiel text</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>blabla beispiel text</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>blabla beispiel text</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
      </div>
    </section> <!-- /content -->

    <footer class="mb-darkgrey-grid-pattern">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Place sticky footer content here.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
<script src="http://mirsoftware.de/muthbau/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: warning: your codepen have a little typo: the html </body> tag is unclosed and it produces an error if the user download it as a zip file (because the appends like jquery come after it).

Comment: Thanks! I updatete it

Comment: "...which has a fix width and is centered" just to let you know: the bar isnt centered on my screen 1280x800, [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/d0ffc0065b030f435c6506bba3c64e1f.png).

Comment: if i remove `position: absolute;` and `top: 150px;` from `.navbar` the bar showsup in the center; but then it creates a new transition jump: now vertical.

Comment: [screenshot 2](https://i.gyazo.com/2b4176d7fb25565f8d910ac04cfa9b0c.png) 1280x800 now without `position: absolute;` and `top: 150px;` on `.navbar`.

Comment: thanks for your investment freestock.tk. But this was not the question. i can fix this later. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are doing many changes on many elements at the same time for no reason. Use only one container to do all your animations, let's say `#headerCollapse`, use transitions and change it's properties just by adding the `.container` class.

```
#headerCollapse {
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position:relative;
}
#headerCollapse:not(.container){
  width:100%;
  height: 69px;
}
#headerCollapse.container{
  height: 186px;
}
```

That way, you have `#headerCollapse` animating from full width and 69px height to `.container` width and 186px height, just by adding `.container` class to it.

The next thing you want to do is to position `.navbar` in a such way that is always stuck to the bottom of `#headerCollapse` and expands to its width.

```
.navbar {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```